# How can I shorten all these && operators in PHP?

Tags: php, operators

I am always slightly confused on how to shorten operators in PHP. They work, but I am sure it could be simpler. An example would be:

`if ($page->template->id == 44 && $page->id != 1020 && $page->id != 1021 && $page->id != 1022 && $page->id != 1023) echo "do something";`

Now in my head it would be:

if the template id is equal to 44, and the page id is equal to 1020 or 1021 or 1022 or 1023 do something

It may not be able to be shortened, but it just feels long to me.

Cheers.

Comment: "Now in my head it would be" - nope....

Comment: One idea is to use PHP's [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Something like `$page->template->id == 44 && !in_array($page->id,range(1020,1023))`. Where do the values come from and what do they represent?

Comment: What's 1020, 1021... and why do you check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ids = [1020,1021,1022,1023];
if ($page->template->id == 44 && ! in_array( $page->id, $ids )) echo "do something"
```

Answer (score 2):

To test if the page is equal to 1020 or 1021 or 1022 or 1023, you can use

```
if(in_array($page->id, [1020, 1021, 1022, 1023])){} // PHP 5.4+
if(in_array($page->id, array(1020, 1021, 1022, 1023))){} // PHP 5.3-
```

Note however that it won't make a strict comparison.